# how to create an upload progressbar during fileupload in php

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I am trying to create an upload progressbar when a file is being uploaded.

This is my part of php:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{   
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
$root = '/users/'.$UserName.'/';
if (!is_dir($root))
{
    @mkdir('users/'.$UserName, 0777);

if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < $MaxUploadSize) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))

{
     echo 'upload successful';

      $data = explode(".",$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      $newfilename = $realname;
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'users/'.$UserName.'/' . $newfilename);

}

else
{

  echo '<span class="failed">Upload failed!</span>';

}

}

} // endif SERVER REQUEST
```

For the progression bar, i use this javascript:

```
var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('#sfmform').ajaxForm({
beforeSend: function() {
    status.empty();
    var percentVal = '0%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
success: function() {
    var percentVal = '100%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);

},
});
```

In combination with: http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js

My form looks like this:

```
 <form id="sfmform" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple"" />

 <br />
<input type="submit" class="Button Primary" name="submit" value="Upload">
<br /><br />

</form>
```

The progressbar works fine, but the php echo's are not being displayed, whether they are successful or when failed. Without the js, the echos work fine!

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Is your php file within <html> </html> tags

Comment: no, i do not use html tags in my php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to receive response in your success call-back:

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
    var percentVal = '100%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);

}
```

Comment: this DOES work but he he alerts the complete html of the page; not only the echo

Comment: because, you need an `exit` right after your `echo` to stop rendering further output.

Comment: You are right. Now it works great! Thanks for the solution

Comment: Glad that it helped you :) Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to check whether the upload was successful and then check that value inside the body of the html

**PHP**

```
$check=0;
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
  //php code
  if (($_FILES["file"]["size"] < $MaxUploadSize) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{

  $check=1;
}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- place your form -->
<?php if ($check==1)
      {
        echo "Upload Successful";
      }
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: no i tried this but withou t result: echos do not show up